# Linq within a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this action in my controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> RiceviListaSpesa([FromBody]List<Prova> ListaAcquisti)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < ListaAcquisti.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ListaAcquisti[i].Scadenza);
            var result = await _context.ProdottiMagazzino.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Prodotto.Codice == ListaAcquisti[i].Codice && p.Scadenza == dt);

        }
        // result = all the row ??
        return (View());
    }
```

What I would do is assign to a variable all the results generated from the query within the loop, to use them outside of the loop

Comment: What is type of ProdottiMagazzino?

Comment: Just declare a List of ProdottiMagazzino outside the for loop, and add each result to that list. At the end you can pass that list as a model to the View or whatever you wanna to do

Comment: ProdottiMagazzino is the model that i have mapped into the db @S.Petrosov

Comment: @S.Petrosov Based on what?

Comment: @Servy I have forgotten that Microsoft has an implementation of the operator for DateTime.

Comment: @S.Petrosov True, not that it's going to be called in this code anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered following:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> RiceviListaSpesa([FromBody]List<Prova> ListaAcquisti)
{
    var results = new List<YourResultType>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ListaAcquisti.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ListaAcquisti[i].Scadenza);
        var result = await _context.ProdottiMagazzino.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Prodotto.Codice == ListaAcquisti[i].Codice && p.Scadenza == dt);
        results.Add(result);
    } 
    // do whatever you need to all the results stored in results list
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not think so